# Calculation in inside of import query on static value

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to only import based on a value.
However, I can't get it to work if it's based on a static value ...

This code works:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:Z20, "SELECT A, Z where ((C/C)*46) >= 200",1)
```

However, the second value I need to divide it from is located in **B40**.
So the following code does not work:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:Z20, "SELECT A, Z where ((C/B40)*46) >= 200",1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:Z20, "SELECT A, Z where ((C/"& Value('Sheet1'!B40) &")*46) >= 200",1)
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: You should mark your answer as "Solved" through the SO interface. Cheers! :)